# How can I make sure each dynamically created image is taking on its own information/data pulled from the API?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for me to make sure each img tag created also contains or can be linked with its individual data from the api? If only one image is returned in the search, it will give me the data for that image. However, if multiple images are returned, once clicked, it will return a only one possible image and data. I am new to coding and javascript in general, so please forgive any rookie mistakes. Thanks!

```
var scryfallURL = "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?q=";
var cardName = "";
var container = $("#list");

$("#searchBtn").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  container.empty();
  cardName = $("#search").val().trim();

  queryURL = scryfallURL + cardName;


  $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
  }).then(function(response) {

    debugger;
    var result = response.data;
    console.log(result);
    $('#search').val('');




    //loops through creating an image tag for each search result
    for (let index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {

      var showCard = $("#list").append("<image src=' " + result[index].image_uris["normal"] + "' ></image>", "</br>");

      var name = result[index].name + "<br>";
      var creature = result[index].type_line + "<br>";
      var flavorText = result[index].flavor_text + "<br>";
      var legality = result[index].legalities + "<br>";
      var cardFront = "<image src=' " + result[index].image_uris["large"] + "' ></image>" + "<br>";

    };

    // click function to clear the div and replace with only one card image and info
    showCard.click(function() {
      $("#searchForm").empty();
      container.empty();
      $("#info").append(name, creature, flavorText, legality);
      $("#oneCard").append(cardFront);
    })

  });

});
```

Comment: what is the output of `result`?

Comment: The 'result' variable outputs all of the information to do with the card. There is quite a bit of information that I can pull from the API per card, but as this is one of my first projects I am trying to keep it simple. Depending on the user input you could get back 70 different cards. I have worked with calling data from the API but not calling an image and then having certain information about that image given back to me 'on click.'